# Node.js script works locally but not locally on firebase serve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, spotify

I'm trying to deploy a modified version of the Spotify web API authorization code + webapp described here. https://github.com/jonnyk20/spotify-node-react-starter-kit/tree/master/auth-server

My react app starts with a screen that has a login button. The user clicks to login, and they're then redirected to the authorization_code node.js script at the link above. They log in, and then are redirected back to the react app, now with the proper Spotify permissions provided.

It works fine when I run everything locally, and I'm able to have the react app portion be fully hosted by firebase while the authorization_code listens locally. However, when I try to get the authorization_code portion to run on firebase, I keep getting the following error after logging in through the OAuth:

```
TypeError: uuid is not a function
    at new Multipart (C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\request\lib\multipart.js:10:19)
    at new Request (C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\request\request.js:125:21)
    at request (C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\request\index.js:53:10)
    at Function.post (C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\request\index.js:61:12)
    at C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\index.js:94:17
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\ryanb\Desktop\Moodify\app\login-test\functions\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

Where line 94 is the beginning of this part of code from the link above.

```
request.post(authOptions, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                var access_token = body.access_token,
                    refresh_token = body.refresh_token;
```

The URL this error displays on is

```
http://localhost:5000/callback?code=AQAG2UXELvI-ymjtxirilFlVE_9zt-tTstXs4TH9YR5zpfWD6xyi6VrGuOgh7Xz_f5cPTJjsR-aFYHj9LxsKRE1HsmSODPadyMOdpLzCDC8k6sNqrehXEmyo3k2tE1MvjJVcFo-wJx3rZrUcnQ_mhFqx2l7IGIiIC1eniux_yHUVu3uRCTj1MCUk7U1ozbRk7kn5MJC4bDHMfS0rvrlie_oo0YpnXj-bkm1rtkmu00Sf_Nl-DiLROmkNjVWNHUAdc4CJcjF6Ml5mBqCSPmUXITbagC_YFKSP0QqaTokcM-IwamGZA2uode5phaseZ9JYnPXILFSiU2Ia3Pgevd8Yrh9PgkKPIbVoM1vWuWSs79KkId2vOBetnrXoVw&state=9aTobHAgxpyMMdb5
```

When I run everything locally, it never goes to the callback url in the web browser; immediately after logging in, I'm redirected to the localhost:3000 with access and refresh tokens in the url, and at that point I'm logged in and ready to go. What am I missing here? I created a new Firebase functions/app deployment folder following the instructions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&t=273s), copying over the code from the link at the beginning of my post and adding the relevant code to index.html. I've tried everything I can think of; this my first time deploying and I'm not super experienced with react or node, and there's nothing online about this error, so I have no idea how to begin interpreting it or how to figure out where I went wrong.

Is there an easier way than what I'm trying to do to host a listening server for a node.js script through firebase?

Note: I don't think this would matter, but I deployed the authorization_code part and the client (react app) part to different firebase projects.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the redirect route specified in your firebase app to the list of redirect URLs in the Spotify developer dashboard?

If you are using the same url as in your local deployment the app will try to redirect your calls made from the firebase app to localhost, which is not going to work.

Add the firebase redirect urls to the developer dashboard and it should work

Comment: I'm currently testing the firebase deployment using `firebase serve`, so I just added localhost:5000 to the list of redirect URLs in the Spotify developer dashboard. I'm getting further errors when I try to actually deploy, but I figured I should at least get it working with firebase serve before I worry about those. Keep in mind that it works fine for the /login call, but when it uses /callback it gives the error.